# Hiding desktop folders using Command Line Interface Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

Realizing that it is possible to change the prefs check-off box in Finder to hide the Hard Drive icon, how would you do this from the command line interface? I.e. what and/or where is the CLI command that emulates the check-off box?

Answer (score 3):

For hiding the Hard Drive you can modify Finder's preferences using the `defaults` command.

Specifically you would want to run:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop -bool NO
```

and relaunch the Finder (using `killall Finder` for example)

For hiding files in general from Finder you can either have `.` in front of the filename (eg. `.hidden Folder`), by turning on the invisible flag using `SetFile`, or using `chflags`.

```
/usr/bin/SetFile -a V /PATH/TO/FILE/OR/FOLDER

chflags hidden /PATH/TO/FILE/OR/FOLDER
```

To reverse:

```
SetFile -a v /PATH/TO/FILE/OR/FOLDER

chflags nohidden /PATH/TO/FILE/OR/FOLDER
```

`SetFile` is installed by default in Snow Leopard but previous versions required you to install the Developer Tools.

Comment: Your one works if you state NO rather than YES (OP wanted to hide not show)

Comment: instead of setfile which requires snow leopard, you can use 'chflags hidden /path/to/file'.

Comment: Fixed and added bits about chflags. Thanks, I forgot about chflags.

Comment: As fyi, `/usr/bin/SetFile` was deprecated with Xcode 6 along as were other tools supporting Carbon development; although `SetFile` still appears to install as some part of Xcode 12 (additional?) tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `SetFile`'s invisible attribute which can be used on files and folders:

```
SetFile -a V /path/to/folder
```

SetFile is not included by default in versions prior to Snow Leopard, but you can get it from the Apple developers kit.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : This is *not* the right answer yet, but hopefully someone can build upon it to make it work :-

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop -bool false && sudo killall Finder
```

Comment: Chealion's version is better (if you say NO rather than YES) - the difference seems to be not specifying a specific path to the plist and just writing to com.apple.finder